# Diagonal difference in Python

Tags: python, diagonal

I am working on a HackerRank problem and I don't understand some of the logic:

```
if (i == j):
    left += a[i][j]
```

The above is saying if the row/column indices are the same([1,1], [2,2], [3,3]), append value found at those coordinates to the list 'left'

I don't understand the logic in the code below. To me it looks like it's saying append values found at the coordinates where row index + column index = 3 (n-1) but I don't think that's right. What would the code below translate to?

```
if (i + j) == (n - 1):
    right += a[i][j]
```

Below is the function with sample inputs a and n.

```
a = [[ 1, 2, 3, 4 ],
     [ 5, 6, 7, 8 ],
     [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ],
     [ 5, 6, 7, 9 ]]

n = 4
def xsum(a, n):
    left = 0
    right = 0
    for i in range(0, n):
        for j in range(0, n):
            if (i == j):
                left += a[i][j]
            if (i + j) == (n - 1):
                right += a[i][j]
    return (abs(left-right))
```

Comment: What's the original question?

Comment: @BrokenBenchmark "Return the absolute difference between the sums of the matrix's two diagonals as a single integer." So the absolute difference between the left and right diagonal sums. The first line of logic gets values from the left diagonal but I don't understand how the right diagonal is traversed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What would the code below translate to?

The code leverages the fact that an element is on the right diagonal if and only if the row and column indices sum to `n - 1`. It then adds the value at the given `(i, j)` pair to `right`.

This can be visualized using the following matrix: each entry is the sum of its row and column index:

```
print([[i + j for i in range(4)] for j in range(4)])
#[[0, 1, 2, 3],
# [1, 2, 3, 4],
# [2, 3, 4, 5], 
# [3, 4, 5, 6]]
# (notice that the n - 1 == 3, and the 3s are only on the antidiagonal!)
```

This is a question about correctness, which is distinct from efficiency. If you're wondering whether this code is efficient, the answer is no: see Chris's answer.

Comment: This was very helpful and I understand now that the right diagonal indices will add up to n-1. Antidiagonals! 

Answer (score 3):

This looks an awful lot like it's working too hard.

If we want to calculate that "left" diagonal.

```
a = [[ 1, 2, 3, 4 ],
     [ 5, 6, 7, 8 ],
     [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ],
     [ 5, 6, 7, 9 ]]

left = []
for i in range(0, 4):
    left.append(a[i][i])
```

Or:

```
left = [a[i][i] for i in range(0, 4)]
```

To find the "right" diagonal.

```
right = [a[i][3 - i] for i in range(0, 4)]
```

If we need to see how this generates a set of indices to index into `a`, we can with the following:

```
>>> [(i, 3 - i) for i in range(0, 4)]
[(0, 3), (1, 2), (2, 1), (3, 0)]
```

Which yields: `[4, 7, 2, 5]`. If you need it reversed.

```
right = [a[3 - i][i] for i in range(0, 4)]
```

This yields: `[5, 2, 7, 4]`.

If we need the sum of the left diagonal, we just need to use the `sum` function: `left_sum = sum(left)`

I've written these examples specifically for a 4x4 matrix. It should be straightforward to generalize this for larger or smaller matrices.

Comment: I've played around a bit with this code you sent. It returns the correct values but I still don't understand how 3-1 traverses the right diagonal.

Comment: Well, when `i` is `0`, we'll access `a[0][3 - 0]` or just `a[0][3]`. When `i` is `1`, we access `a[1][2]`, when `i` is `2`, `a[2][1]`, and when `i` is `3`, `a[3][0]`.

Comment: I get it now. And writing it as a list comprehension makes it all the more elegant/efficient. Seeing the code dissected this way really helped me to understand.

Answer (score 1):

```
def diagonalDifference(arr):

    mat = len(arr[0]) #type of matrix e.g(3by3)
    left_sum = 0
    right_sum =0
    k =mat-1 #rightmost element accessor 

    for i in range(mat):
        left_sum += arr[i][i] 

    for j in range(mat):
        right_sum += arr[j][k]
        k-=1

    return abs(right_sum - left_sum)
```